# File type missing in file upload

Tags: php, html, csv

I have a page that will allow me to upload a CSV file.  Using PHP I then take the contents of the CSV file and insert them into a MySQL database.  I've been doing this with no problems for awhile now.  Then today, I tried uploading the file and it didn't work.  The problem is that there appears to be no file type associated with the CSV file.  For example, on a good upload, the debug messages I spit out look like this:

```
You uploaded a file: buylist_235.csv 
file type: application/vnd.ms-excel 
file size: 10456 

File is valid, and was successfully uploaded. Here is some more debugging info:Array (
        [csv] => Array
            (
                [name] => buylist_235.csv
                [type] => application/vnd.ms-excel
                [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php3C1E.tmp
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 10456
            )
)
```

However, when I upload the problem file with the debug messages on I noticed the file type and file size is empty.

```
You uploaded a file: buylist_235_1.csv
file type: 
file size: 0

Possible file upload attack!
Here is some more debugging info:Array
(
    [csv] => Array
        (
            [name] => buylist_235_1.csv
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 2
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

Anyone have any ideas why the file type is empty?  In Windows Explorer, if I hover over either of these files the info balloon over the files say "Type: Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File".  But there is something wrong with the second file that causes my PHP to puke and not recognize the file type.

Comment: What do the files look like?

Comment: its a standard CSV file.  It has 7 columns and then the number of rows is variable.  I had the MAX_FILE_SIZE set to 30KB.  All previous files were easily under that.  This particular file was much larger, around 70KB.  So the file itself was fine, it was bad HTML code as Patrick points out below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file type is not the problem (I don't think).

You'll see `error` code 2 was returned during the attempted file upload in your second example block, and it was NOT written to temporary storage (`tmp_name` is empty, `size` is 0).

```
You uploaded a file: buylist_235_1.csv
file type: 
file size: 0

Possible file upload attack!
Here is some more debugging info:Array
(
    [csv] => Array
        (
            [name] => buylist_235_1.csv
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 2
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

**Error code 2 is: *UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE*:** The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.

Adjust this value larger in your form HTML.

Comment: Thanks!  The size was the problem.  As soon as I increased it the upload worked fine.